# WCF Exception Handaling

Tags: wcf, exception

I have five separate services where each one corresponds to a different database table such as Product, User, Orders etc.

I am trying to send my custom exceptions across WCF. I have browsed the internet and i have wrapped my custom exceptions inside a fault exception:

```
interface
[FaultContract(typeof(NoSuchInstanceException))] 

cs
throw new FaultException<NoSuchInstanceException>(e, new FaultReason(e.Message), newFaultCode("UserFault"));
```

The problem is when i update the service the client proxy disappears. I browsed the internet and found the following solution which says to add a mapping to the service reference SVCMAP file. http://travisspencer.com/blog/2007/11/

```
<NamespaceMapping
    TargetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyCompany.MyProject.Exceptions" ClrNamespace="MyCompany.MyProject.Exceptions" />
</NamespaceMappings>
```

My problem is that every service needs the custom exceptions adding to the mapping but when i do this. An error is displayed saying the exception is already defined in one of the other services. Do i merge the services into one service? Any help is really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: _"The problem is when i update the service the client proxy disappears. "_ Please elaborate.

Comment: @CodeCaster: When i add: [FaultContract(typeof(NoSuchInstanceException))] To my service interface and update my service reference. The service client and iservice client disappear and a warning is displayed saying "Check if the required namespace has been mapped to a different data contract namespace and consider mapping it explicitly using the namespaces collection." The same error is displayed in the blog above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two options:

- Merge the services into one - having multiple services sharing the same data types gives this problem on the client.
- Move the shared data types into a separate dll (class library project). Then reference that shared data type library from both your server and client. When you create the services reference, choose the option to reuse data types.

Comment: _"having multiple services sharing the same data types gives this problem on the client."_ Yeah, I wouldn't dare sending a String from two different services. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @CodeCaster: string is a native data type, that behaves very much like when you have a shared data type library. If you have a custom type and return it from two different services, that custom type will be generated twice on the client - once for each service.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think the first option is the only possible one. I don't want to have to provide the dll to anyone that consumes my service. I'm not that keen on having one huge service. Is there not a way of having a parent service with children? Is this the cleanest solution for having multiple services as one service? http://www.meineck.net/2008/04/wcf-hosting-multiple-wcf-services-as.html